# Why does my view's background change during an animation?

Tags: android, background-color, android-animation, android-3.0-honeycomb

Simple animation; I just want something to slide away to the left.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="0"
               android:toXDelta="-100%"
               android:duration="1000"/>
</set>
```

I have an ExpandableListView:

```
<ExpandableListView android:id="@id/android:list"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    ... />
```

To which I apply this:

```
ExpandableListView list = getExpandableListView();
Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(TvEventListActivity.this, R.anim.left);
list.startAnimation(anim);
```

When I start the animation, the list background, which should be transparent, changes to a solid grey background for the duration of the animation.  Then it is restored to correctness.

Why does this happen?  How can I prevent it?

Comment: What is your ExpandableListView's `android:cacheColorHint` value?

Comment: I had not set it at all.  Setting it to `@android:color/transparent` solved the problem.  Type that as an answer and I'll check-mark it.  :)

Comment: Also the `<set>` tags were unnecessary.  I removed them and just made `<translate>` be the root.

Comment: For some background info you might want to read this article: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/why-is-my-list-black-android.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to set your `android:cacheColorHint` to transparent if a background Drawable is used or the same background color if a solid color is used.